# Xamarin.InAppBilling Android error: Your order could not be processed. Please try again

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to implement in-app purchases, and have followed the documentation to the letter.

The app was published in the store with in-app purchases enabled. Our store account has active products and subscriptions, but trying to buy with ~20 different accounts, we all get `"Your order could not be processed. Please try again".` after inputting credit card info.

I triple checked our public key for the store and our purchases IDs. Using the Google test IDs, the app works. In-app purchases worked ~6 months ago.

These are the 2 errors I see in  my device log:

> - purchasefragment error purchaseerror type 2 subtype 0
> - unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/ees/commitPurchase

We have written the app in Xamarin and are using the [Xamarin.InAppBilling component](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.inappbilling).

```
private InAppBillingServiceConnection _serviceConnection;
    private IEnumerable<Product> _availableProducts;

    //public event EventHandler<PurchaseCanceledEventArgs> PurchaseCanceled;
    public event EventHandler<PurchaseFailedEventArgs> PurchaseFailed;
    public event EventHandler<PurchaseSucceededEventArgs> PurchaseSucceeded;

    public void Buy(string productId)
    {
        if (_serviceConnection.Connected)
        {
            if (_availableProducts != null && _availableProducts.Any())
            {
                var product = _availableProducts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductId.Equals(productId));
                if (product != null)
                {
                    _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.BuyProduct(product);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public PurchaseProduct GetProduct(string productId)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool HasSubscriptionFor(string productIdentifier)
    {
        if (_serviceConnection?.BillingHandler != null)
        {
            return _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.GetPurchases(ItemType.Subscription).Any(x => x.ProductId == productIdentifier);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void RestorePreviousPurchases()
    {
        // Restore not required for google purchases (?)
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            _serviceConnection?.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    public void Connect(Activity activity)
    {
        try
        {
            _serviceConnection = new InAppBillingServiceConnection(activity, "our public key");
            _serviceConnection.OnConnected += OnConnected;
            _serviceConnection.Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private async void OnConnected()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            if (_serviceConnection?.BillingHandler != null)
            {
                _serviceConnection.OnInAppBillingError += OnInAppBillingError;
                _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnProductPurchased += BillingHandlerOnOnProductPurchased;
                _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnProductPurchasedError += BillingHandlerOnOnProductPurchasedError;
                _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.BuyProductError += BillingHandlerOnBuyProductError;

                // Test in sandbox mode only
                //_availableProducts = await _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync(new List<string>
                //{
                //    ReservedTestProductIDs.Purchased,
                //    ReservedTestProductIDs.Refunded,
                //    ReservedTestProductIDs.Canceled,
                //    ReservedTestProductIDs.Unavailable
                //}, ItemType.Product);

                var products = await _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync(_purchaseConfiguration.Products, ItemType.Product);
                var subscriptions = await _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync(_purchaseConfiguration.Subscriptions, ItemType.Subscription);

                _availableProducts = new List<Product>();
                if (products?.Any() == true)
                {
                    _availableProducts = _availableProducts.Concat(products);
                }

                if (subscriptions?.Any() == true)
                {
                    _availableProducts = _availableProducts.Concat(subscriptions);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void HandleResult(int requestCode, object resultCode, object data)
    {
        _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.HandleActivityResult(requestCode, (Result)resultCode, (Intent)data);
    }

    private void BillingHandlerOnBuyProductError(int responseCode, string sku)
    {
        PurchaseFailed?.Invoke(this, new PurchaseFailedEventArgs { Message = "BillingHandlerOnBuyProductError: " + sku });
    }

    private void BillingHandlerOnOnProductPurchasedError(int responseCode, string sku)
    {
        PurchaseFailed?.Invoke(this, new PurchaseFailedEventArgs { Message = "BillingHandlerOnBuyProductError: " + sku });
    }

    private void BillingHandlerOnOnProductPurchased(int response, Purchase purchase, string purchaseData, string purchaseSignature)
    {
        PurchaseSucceeded?.Invoke(this, new PurchaseSucceededEventArgs(purchase.ProductId));
    }

    private void OnInAppBillingError(InAppBillingErrorType error, string message)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            PurchaseFailed?.Invoke(this, new PurchaseFailedEventArgs { Message = message });
        }
    }
```

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="3.0.14" package="">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
  <application android:label="" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/ApplicationBaseTheme" android:largeHeap="true" android:allowBackup="false">    
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="%PACKAGE_NAME%" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.pushwoosh.GCMInstanceIDListenerService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName" android:value="@string/facebook_app_name" />
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <permission android:name="%PACKAGE_NAME%.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="%PACKAGE_NAME%.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <!--for Samsung-->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"/>
  <!--for htc-->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"/>
  <!--for sony-->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
  <!--for apex-->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"/>
  <!--for solid-->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: If the log is pasted from real log, check typo. It says "aBdroid". And response code 500 maybe "internal server error" (if it's a net response)

Comment: Is your app set as `Published`? or is it still `Ready to Publish`? It needs to be Published for InApp purchases to work, if it is still in Alpha release, it will not show in the Store, but will be eligible for Purchases as long as it is published...

Comment: @SushiHangover the app is published and live in the store

Comment: @Toris this was a typo on my site, I updated the post

Comment: Same issue. Was this ever resolved?